# How to pick location like whatsapp does?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, share

im running and app and i want it to be able to let the user pick the location like whatsapp does when you are sharing a location. The main idea is to let the user decide to show a place close where he is. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check Google Places API (https://developers.google.com/places/training/?hl=en), send a query to them with your location and the filters you want to specify: kind of near places, distance, sort by relevance or distance... and show them where you need =)